# Angular Translation is not available for pagination buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate and partial loader to load my translations. The normal text translation works just fine, however the translation is not visible on the pagination buttons. I have a minimum working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/vNT0nQvBAKZb8RnFpjkE?p=preview.

The pagination directive looks like:

```
  <ul uib-pagination ng-model="currentPage" 
                  total-items="rows.length" 
                  max-size="maxSize" 
                  boundary-links="true" 
                  first-text="{{'FIRST_TEXT'|translate}}" 
                  previous-text="{{'PREVIOUS_TEXT'|translate}}" 
                  next-text="{{'NEXT_TEXT'|translate}}" 
                  last-text="{{'LAST_TEXT'|translate}}">
  </ul>
```

Can anyone please have a look if I am missing any configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: I've spent quite some time on this, and it looks to be impossible based on the requirements in the post by @sajeetharan. There was also an issue opened on this a while back: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4481.

Comment: from `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.js` version its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got some tweaks to make your pagination text change on translation. Actually I did nothing on $translate lib, I played along uib pagination DOM manipulation.

Also for the first time to set text it needs a delay.

plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/sZ5J2qaqDOLcg76MgicM?p=preview

Changed function:

```
function NavigationController($scope,$rootScope, $translate, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.refreshPagination = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      $translate.use($translate.use()).then(function(){
        refreshPaginationItems();
      });
    }, 1000);
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (langkey) {
      $translate.use(langkey).then(function(){
        refreshPaginationItems();
      });
    }

    function refreshPaginationItems(){
      $rootScope.refreshPagination = false;
      $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.refreshPagination = true;
      }, 0);
    }
  }
```

I have not refactored the code. In case you think the better option please feel free to opt for it.

Comment: Hi Samir, thank you for the answer. What I don't get is where are you using the `refreshPagination` variable?

Comment: it's in index.html <ul ng-if="refreshPagination"

Comment: another quick question, why are you doing `$timeout(function() {.... }, 0`, timeout with 0 second in `refreshPagination`?

Comment: we are re-initializing UI-Pagination block using ng-if, once we have new translations in place. To make it impact on UI View I have added $timeout function to provide a sort of delay!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in controller by creating a $scope variable,

```
  function ProfessionalController($scope, $rootScope, $translate) {
    $scope.filteredRows = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.numPerPage = 10;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;
    $scope.previousText;
    $scope.nextText;

    $translate(['PREVIOUS', 'NEXT']).then(function(translations) {
      $scope.previousText = translations.PREVIOUS;
      $scope.nextText = translations.NEXT;
    });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <ul uib-pagination ng-model="currentPage" 
                      total-items="rows.length" 
                      max-size="maxSize" 
                      boundary-links="true" 
                      first-text="{{'FIRST_TEXT'|translate}}" 
                      previous-text="{{previousText}}" 
                      next-text="{{nextText}}" 
                      last-text="{{'LAST_TEXT'|translate}}">
      </ul>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/CFRwUQndsQZloRROOQnO?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sharing my pagination across multiple pages and there are many translations in my application. That is why I was using the partial loader of angular template. Such that I don't have to duplicate my translation for pagination button across different pages. Rather than defining the translation text in the controller I would like to use the partial translation files.